# Shuffle images between multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a codepen of some code.  The card flips work as intended but cannot get the shuffle portion to work.  The images disappear.  The back image (image 2-5) will disappear until the page is reset instead of shuffling to the other cards.  I'm at a loss of what to do.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kyledrew/pen/wbOBwe)

How its supposed to work is when I click the shuffle button, images 2-5 move randomly to the back of the other cards either on load of page or when button is pressed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as to where I went wrong.

Here is the code I'm using

```
function shuffle() {
$(".shuffleImg").each(function() {
  var divs = $(this).find(".images");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) $(divs[i]).remove();

  var i = divs.length;
  if (i == 0) return false;
  while (--i) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tempi = divs[i];
    var tempj = divs[j];
    divs[i] = tempj;
    divs[j] = tempi;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) $(divs[i]).appendTo(this);
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the div to another part of the document, inside

```
<div class="container shuffleImg">
```

by the side of

```
<div class="row">
```

Because you are using the parameter `this` in `appendTo`.
What you should put an ID to each card, and select use it to call the `appendTo`

```
<div class="container shuffleImg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card-container manual-flip">
        <div class="card box" onclick="rotateCard(this)" id="cardbox1">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image 1" />
          </div>
          <div class="back images">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image 2" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card-container manual-flip">
        <div class="card box" onclick="rotateCard(this)" id="cardbox2">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image 1" />
          </div>
          <div class="back images">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image 3" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card-container manual-flip">
        <div class="card box" onclick="rotateCard(this)" id="cardbox3">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image 1" />
          </div>
          <div class="back images">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image 4" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card-container manual-flip">
        <div class="card box" onclick="rotateCard(this)" id="cardbox4">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image 1" />
          </div>
          <div class="back images">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image 5" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the Javascript code

```
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    $(divs[i]).appendTo($('#cardbox'+(i+1)));
}
```